# Can I use System.js without ES6

Tags: jquery, angularjs, electron, jspm, systemjs

Long story so I'll try and keep it short.

I am trying to build an Angular application. I works just fine in the browser but when I try and use electron to present it jQuery doesn't load.

The solution [on the electron site](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/254) goes like this

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js');
```

I'm not using require, but have used jspm to setup parts of my project. It seems I need to write some kind of bootstrapper, but all examples are in ES6 and I don't want to have to rewrite all my angular code to make it work.

I think all I have to do is get rid of my `ng-app="app"` at the top of the html file and include something like this

```
<script>
    System.import('./src/app').then(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

but I get `angular is undefined` errors